# Get text of an element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html and try to get the text (i.e. Brand:Adidas) from each `<li class="col-xs-2">`.

```
<div class="row text-secondary">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <ul class="row">
                <li class="col-xs-2">
                    Brand: 
                    Adidas
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-2">
                    Colour: Black
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-2">
                    Model:
                    New
                </li>
                <li class="col-xs-2">
                    Size: 
                    2 
                </li>
```

Like this:

```
if ($(".row.text-secondary")[0]){
    $('div.text-secondary div.col-xs-2 ul.row li.col-xs-2').each(function () {
    var Var1 = [];
    var Var2 = [];
    var Var3 = [];

    Var1 = $(this).text();
    Var2 = Var1.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g, "");
    Var3.push(Var2);
});
} else{
    var Var3 = ["NotAvailable", "NotAvailable", "NotAvailable","NotAvailable"];
}
```

But when I save to database I get blank values where `if ($(".row.text-secondary")[0])` evaluates to `true`(also if I use `if ($(".row.text-secondary").length)`. I only get correct answer if the conditions above evaluate to `false`, then I get `NotAvalaible`.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use condition `$(".row.text-secondary")!=null`

Also `Var1` and `Var2` are strings not arrays

`Var3` must be declared outside if block

Also, if you only want the value discarding the field name use

```
var Var2 = Var1.substring(Var1.indexOf(":") + 1).replace(/[\n\t\r]/g, "").trim();
```

instead of

var Var2 = Var1.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g, "");

First option will generate an array having `["Adidas", "Black", "New", "2"]`

Hope it helps,

```
var Var3 = [];
if ($("div.row.text-secondary")!=null){
    $('div.text-secondary div.col-xs-2 ul.row li.col-xs-2').each(function () {
       Var1 = $(this).text();
       var Var2 = Var1.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g, "");
       Var3.push(Var2);
});
} else{
    Var3 = ["NotAvailable", "NotAvailable", "NotAvailable","NotAvailable"];
}
```

Comment: One would think the OP had a reason for the more restrictive CSS selectors, no?

Comment: @caasjj What do you mean?

Comment: my bad @caasjj updated the selectors to match the original ones

Comment: $("div.row.text-secondary")[0] is not a valid condition. Not sure why length didn't work